# Find best orthogonal transformation matrix

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, linear-transformations, matrix-equations, transformation

I have a matrices $A_{K \times M}$ and $B_{K \times N}$
I am looking for an orthogonal matrix $T_{M \times N}$ such that minimize:

$\mathrm{arg\,min}_{T} ||A T - B||$

(on other words: the best orthogonal transformation from A to B).

I found this https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Orthogonal_Procrustes_problem#Generalized/constrained_Procrustes_problems algorithm to find best orthogonal transformation, but it only applies to matrices of the same size.

how can I find this T?

Comment: Normally, the term "orthogonal" only applies to square matrices. What exactly do you mean when you say that the matrix $T$ is "orthogonal"?

Comment: It means that all of T's columns are orthogonal to each other (but T is not a square matrix)

Comment: One idea: if we begin along the lines of the proof from the Wiki page, we might note that
$$
\|AT - B\|^2 = \operatorname{tr}((AT - B)^\top (AT - B))\\
= \|AT\|_F^2 + \|B\|_F^2 - 2\operatorname{tr}(T^\top A^\top B)
$$
This doesn't lead to an obvious way forward. Perhaps it would help to express $T$ in the form $T = UJ$, where
$$
J = \pmatrix{I\\0}
$$
and $U$ is a square orthogonal matrix.